# What genre is the background song in Spike's dream scene in *Cowboy Bebop: The Movie*?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre, jazz

I found a video from [*Cowboy Bebop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_Bebop:_The_Movie) titled [*Cowboy Bebop: The Movie [HD] - Spike's Dream Scene (Blu-Ray)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNGmr5qPso0&feature=youtu.be) on YouTube. I have seen it many times, and I'm really interested in the piano playing in the soundtrack starting at [2:41](https://youtu.be/FNGmr5qPso0?t=161). Does anyone know what genre of jazz or music style is used in this soundtrack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a piano/violin duet from the sounds of it. I wouldn't classify this as jazz necessarily. It sounds like a movie score more than a 'genre' in my opinion. 'Smooth Jazz' would be your best bet, it isn't quite 'Cool Jazz'.

Comment: thk you,i did find that the smooth jazz and romantic smooth jazz piano play similar to this,but it's still not one hundred percent correct.i thought it was jazz because it has some post modern style and jazz chords.

Comment: it's not at all smooth jazz

Answer (score -1):

The Cowboy Bebop soundtrack is composed of some genres and sub-genres of jazz and blues. If you look for Big Band in Spotify, you will find some stuff that you may like. You should also search for Delta Blues — that may remind you of Cowboy Bebop.